# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 flutter

Tags: flutter

I have listView to display the images that were previously stored in the database and display them to the user.
The images are fetched and displayed to the user correctly, but I have a different problem. I put a button to add more images that I get from the phone using the library:
https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker
and they are added to the listview with  images that come from the database  and display them all to the user in listview.

Now my problem if I select one image by this library I get this problem:

```
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      List.elementAt (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:476:16)
#2      _update_profiletttState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_application_1/testpage.dart:178:76)
#3      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:456:22)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1214:28)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1147:67)
#6      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:35)
#7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1191:24
```

But if I select more than one image like two I Don't face this problem.

Full page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:wechat_assets_picker/wechat_assets_picker.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(
  ‏    MyApp(),
  ‏  );
  ‏}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  ‏  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ‏    return MaterialApp(
  ‏      home: UpdateItem(),
  ‏    );
  ‏  }
  ‏}
class UpdateItem extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ‏  _update_profiletttState createState() => new _update_profiletttState();
  ‏}
class _update_profiletttState extends State<UpdateItem> {

  @override
  ‏  void initState() {
  ‏    super.initState();
  ‏    init();
  ‏  }
  void init() {
    GetImage().then((value) {
    ‏      setState(() {
    ‏        users.addAll(value);
    ‏        filteredUsers = users;
      });
      ‏    });
      ‏  }
  List<DataImage> users = [];
  ‏  List<DataImage> filteredUsers = [];


  final _formKeys = GlobalKey<FormState>();



  String api;
  ‏  Future<List<DataImage>> GetImage() async {
  ‏    api = 'https://***************.php' ;
  ‏    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(api));
  ‏    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  ‏      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  ‏      List<DataImage> listOfFruits = items.map<DataImage>((json) {
  ‏        return DataImage.fromJson(json);
  ‏      }).toList();
  ‏      return listOfFruits;
  ‏    }
  }
  ‏  
  ‏  List<AssetEntity> assets = <AssetEntity>[];
  ‏  
  ‏  @override
  ‏  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  MaterialApp(
    ‏      home: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
        ‏            key: _formKeys,
        ‏            child:  Center(
        ‏              child:   ListView(
        ‏                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                  ‏                    child: new Column(
                  ‏                      children: <Widget>[
                  ‏                        Container(
                  ‏                          child: Center(
                  ‏                            child: Column(
                  ‏                              children: <Widget>[
                  ‏                                Padding(
                  ‏                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ‏                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  ‏                                    child: SizedBox(
                  ‏                                      child: Column(
                  ‏                                        //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  ‏                                        //   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  ‏                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Column(
                                          ‏                                            children: <Widget>[
                                          ‏                                              AnimatedContainer(
                                          ‏                                                duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                                          ‏                                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                                          ‏                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                          ‏                                                height: filteredUsers.isNotEmpty ? 100.0 : 0.0,
                                          ‏                                                child: ListView.builder(
                                          ‏                                                    physics:  BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                    ‏                                                    itemCount: filteredUsers.length + 1  ,
                                                    ‏                                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                      if (index < filteredUsers.length) {
                                                      ‏                                                        return Container(
                                                      ‏                                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      ‏                                                              horizontal: 0.5, vertical: 6.0),
                                                      ‏                                                          child: AspectRatio(
                                                      ‏                                                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                                                      ‏                                                            child: Stack(
                                                      ‏                                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                                filteredUsers[index].isLocal ?
                                                                ‏                                                                    
                                                                Image(
                                                                ‏                                                                  image: AssetEntityImageProvider(
                                                                    assets.elementAt(index) ,
                                                                    ‏                                                                    isOriginal: false,
                                                                    ‏                                                                  ),
                                                                    ‏                                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                    ‏                                                                )

                                                                    : Image.network(
                                                                    ‏                                                                  filteredUsers[index].ImageURL.toString(),
                                                                    ‏                                                                  width: double.infinity,
                                                                    ‏                                                                  height: 400,
                                                                    ‏                                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                    ‏                                                                ),



                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            ‏                                                          ),
                                                            ‏                                                        );
                                                            ‏                                                      }
                                                            ‏                                                      else {
                                                        return
                                                        ‏                                                          IconButton(
                                                        ‏                                                            icon: Icon(Icons.add,size: 50,),
                                                        ‏                                                            onPressed: ()  async {
                                                              final List<AssetEntity> result = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(context,
                                                              ‏                                                                  maxAssets: 4,
                                                              ‏                                                                  pathThumbSize: 84,
                                                              ‏                                                                  gridCount: 4,
                                                              ‏                                                                  selectedAssets: assets,
                                                                  //we use this for languge
                                                                  ‏                                                                  textDelegate: EnglishTextDelegate());
                                                              if (result != null) {
                                                              ‏                                                                setState(() {
                                                                  assets = List<AssetEntity>.from(result);
                                                                  filteredUsers.add(DataImage(  isLocal: true));

                                                                });
                                                                ‏                                                              }


                                                            },
                                                            ‏                                                          );
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  //itemBuilder: assetItemBuilder,
                                                  ‏                                                ),
                                                  ‏                                              )
                                            ],
                                            ‏                                          ),
                                        ],
                                        ‏                                      ),
                                        ‏                                    ),
                                        ‏                                  ),
                                        ‏                                ),
                                        ‏                              ],
                                        ‏                            ),
                                        ‏                          ),
                                        ‏                        ),
                                        ‏                        /*     Card(
                                        ‏                                child: showImage(),
                                        ‏                              ),*/
                      ],
                      ‏                    ),
                      ‏                  ),

                ],
                ‏              ),
                ‏            )),
                ‏      ),
                ‏    );
                ‏  }


}
class DataImage {

  bool isLocal;
  ‏  String ImageURL;

  DataImage(
  ‏      { this.ImageURL, this.isLocal = false});
  factory DataImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  ‏    return DataImage(
      ImageURL: json['image'].toString(),
    );
    ‏  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'ImageURL': ImageURL,
    ‏    'isLocal': isLocal,
  };

}
```

How can this problem be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 itemCount: filteredUsers.length + 1
```

To this:

```
 itemCount: filteredUsers.length
```

Comment: Hello brother, it did not work, the problem still